# Cryptography decryption on secret suffix without knowing the secret key

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I was having this problem in cryptography. The problem is I have to find the secret suffix, s by querying from Oracle without knowing the encryption key, k.

The information that I have on how the encryption was done is it was done using ECB mode under DES with 56-bit key and input block size of 64 bit.

So my question is, what are the steps for the decryption given all the information above. From my research, I found out that the attacker stands no chance with given ciphertext only. So I was wondering if it is possible to attack it in this case?

The main function that I was given is as follow:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String key = "3%ac^`+=";  // a different key
    String ciphertext = "a(19q-j*"; // a different suffix
    Oracle1 oracle = new Oracle1(key.getBytes(), ciphertext.getBytes());
    Attacker1 attacker = new Attacker1(oracle);
    byte[] res = attacker.decryptCiphertext();
    // should be true
    System.out.println(isConsistent(ciphertext, res));
}
```

I am supposed to perform the attack in decryptCiphertext() and return the result as byte array then compare with the given ciphertext. If the comparison result is true, then it is the correct one.

**Oracle.java**

```
public class Oracle1 {

private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Oracle1.class);

final private byte[] SuffixBytes;

private Cipher cipher;
private static String ALGO = Config.ALGO;
private static int BlockSize = getAlgoBlockSize(ALGO);

public Oracle1() {
    this(Config.p1Key, Config.p1Suffix);
}

private void init(byte[] keyBytes) {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    SecretKey KEY;
    try {
        if (isSizeLegal(keyBytes, ALGO)) {
            KEY = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, ALGO);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("illegal ALGO %s with key length %d", ALGO, keyBytes.length));
        }
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(String.format("%s/ECB/NoPadding", ALGO));
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, KEY);
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

public Oracle1(byte[] keyBytes, byte[] suffixBytes) {
    SuffixBytes = suffixBytes;
    init(keyBytes);
}

public Oracle1(String keyString, String suffixString) {
    byte[] keyBytes = keyString.getBytes();
    SuffixBytes = suffixString.getBytes();
    init(keyBytes);
}

public byte[] compose(String plainText) {
    return compose(plainText.getBytes());
}

public byte[] compose(byte[] bytes) {
    int byteLength = bytes.length;
    if (byteLength > BlockSize) {
        logger.info("input length {} > {}", byteLength, BlockSize);
    }

    byte[] inputBytes = concat(bytes, SuffixBytes);
    byte[] finalBytes = paddingBytes(inputBytes, BlockSize);
    byte[] cipherBytes = new byte[0];
    try {
        cipherBytes = cipher.doFinal(finalBytes);
        logger.info("input:{}\tcipher:{}", finalBytes, cipherBytes);
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return cipherBytes;
}

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How much ciphertext do you have? Is it actual, coherent text? DES can be brute-forced, but my understanding is that that would require it to be actual, coherent text - if they're encrypting some random characters and you don't have any coherent text to brute force or some kind of known- or chosen- plaintext, then I'm not sure how you could possibly verify that what you have is the correct solution (and please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: The key and suffix that I was given was in these formats. suffix = "a(19q-j*", key="3%ac^`+=".  Let me upload the main function I was given.

Comment: I am sorry, suffix is the ciphertext. Let me update the question

Comment: @EJoshuaS 1. The term you are searching for is "crib", some part of the encrypted message that is known and can be used to determine if the message is correctly decrypted. 2. Try brute forcing a 56-bit DES key, it will on average only take 10,000,000,000,000,000 decryption tries. Yes DES is weak and should not be used, no it is not quick to brute force.

Comment: @zaph Thanks, that's the term I was looking for.

Comment: @zaph I was advised not to attack it with brute force cause it has to be done within 2 minutes. Is there any other approach I can use given these limited information?

Comment: The `ciphertext` "a(19q-j*" is interesting, because encrypted text is binary and it would be extremely rare for 8 binary bytes to also be ASCII encodable, about a 1 in 2500 chance or less. Please explain "from Oracle", it this some kind of decryption Oracle and if so what is known about it.

Comment: I have uploaded the Oracle class. It has a compose() which will execute the .doFinal to perform the decryption. I not sure if I am supposed to call the compose() multiple times in decryptCiphertext() in order to guess the secret suffix. I am at a total lost actually.

Comment: What does `paddingBytes` do?

Comment: @matt It's a class given and I am not supposed to touch anything inside there. But from what I have learnt, the padding is to remove blank space from the text if I am not wrong.

Comment: @DeniseTan on second thought I don’t think you need to know what `paddingBytes` does.

Comment: @matt I see but do you have any ideas? Or my understanding for the question was totally off track?

Answer (score 2):

We have an encryption Oracle that allows us to send a message `M` and will return `E(M|S)` (meaning the encryption of `M` + `S` where is the suffix). The challenge is to determine `S`. I assume the key and suffix given are test data to enable testing the code before trying it out “for real” (since if we know the key we can just decrypt the result ourself).

Since the encryption is using ECB, each block is encrypted independently. We can use that to determine `S`.

DES has a block size of 8 bytes. If we create an input that is 7 bytes long (e.g. 7 0x00 bytes) then the Oracle will append `S` and then encrypt the result. This means the first block of the resulting ciphertext will be the encryption of

```
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 X
```

where `X` is the first byte of `S`. We make a note of this ciphertext.

If we then send a series of 8 byte blocks, where we vary the final byte like this:

```
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x02
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x03
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x04
...
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xff
```

and compare them to the unknown ciphertext we will find one that matches. There are only 256 such blocks so this will not take long. We then know the first byte of the suffix.

We can then repeat this procedure for the next byte, but instead of a 7 byte message first we send a 6 byte message, and then we construct our (up to) 256 test messages using the now known first byte, so if the first byte is for example 0x55 they will look like

```
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x55 0x01
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x55 0x02
...
```

Repeating this, we can determine `S` one byte at a time.

---

Looking at the code you’ve given, I *think* the idea might be for you to implement the `Attacker1` class, calling `oracle.compose()` multiple times from within the `decryptSuffix()` method. The `main` method you have would then be used to test your code. You would then submit this class and it would be tested with a “real” oracle.

Comment: @zaph it doesn’t look like a padding oracle, although at first I thought it was, but rather a “byte at a time ecb decryption” (for want of a better name). A padding oracle works with CBC mode and leaks info when _decrypting_ input, but this is ECB mode and is _encrypting_ input.

Comment: @zaph Here’s my implementation of this attack: https://github.com/mattwildig/cryptopals/blob/master/set2/challenge14/ecb-decrypt.go from [cryptopals challenge 12](http://cryptopals.com/sets/2/challenges/12) (it’s not the best code—I was using it to learn Go at the same time).

Comment: @matt Yeah that is what I need to do actually, sorry for the bad explanation of the question! So what I am supposed to do is pass in the given ciphertext into decryptSuffix() and keep on querying compose()? But then how do I determine S one byte at a time? Sorry but I got lost again after looking at the code example you provided

Comment: @matt Sorry but correct me if I am wrong. So firstly I need to create another input of 7 bytes, eg String input = "a(19q-j" then call the compose() and store it as byte array. Then after that, I will use the original 8 bytes input and call the compose() and store it as another byte array. Then after that, I compare both of the byte array and find matches and I will obtain the first byte and I store it as byteResult. Then, I repeat for 6 bytes, 5 bytes etc. But every time I found a match, I append it to byteResult?